# Replacing all the empty elements in an array with a String value

Tags: c#

I have an array which can hold 10 elements:

```
string[] Ar = new string[10];
```

But it has only 5 items added to it. I need to insert The string value "NULL" to the rest of the empty slots in the array and thus making the array 'full' with string elements (that, being my objective).

This is what I've attempted as of now:

```
int entityCount = 5;

if (entityCount < 10)
{
    for (int i = entityCount; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Ar[i] = "NULL";
    }
}
```

And thus, when printed should output the values:

> A, B, C, D, E, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

But this does not seem to do the trick, Still prints out ONLY the 5 items and not the 5 new strings.

Comment: What's your question? This looks like it should work. Also what language are you in?

Comment: C#. I want to fill up the array by replacing the empty slots with the string "NULL", thus being able to print: "A, B, C, D, E, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL" :)

Comment: Your code is correct...

Comment: How are you printing the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not from C# background but I think this is what you want:

```
string[] Ar = new string[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Ar[i]))
  {
    Ar[i]="NULL";
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(Ar[i]);
}
```

You can read about `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Ar[i])` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is in C# only :D

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. This worked just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int arraySize = 10;
        string[] Ar = new string[arraySize];

        Ar[0] = "A";
        Ar[1] = "B";
        Ar[2] = "C";
        Ar[3] = "D";

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            if (Ar[i]==null)
            {
                Ar[i] = "NULL";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Ar.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(Ar[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine.

```
int entityCount = 5;

string[] Ar = new string[10];
Ar[0] = "A";
Ar[1] = "B";
Ar[2] = "C";
Ar[3] = "D";
Ar[4] = "E";

if(entityCount < 10) {
    for(int i = entityCount; i < 10; i++) {
        Ar[i] = "NULL";
    }
}

foreach(string s in Ar) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] Ar = new string[10];

        var item = from f in Ar
                   select string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f) ? "NULL" : f;

        foreach (var i in item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here item is iterator in string of array replace all with null if not contains value
string multiplayer = new string[5];

```
foreach (var item in multiplayers)
{
     if (item == null) { Console.WriteLine("Empty"); }
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

remember string of array is not `nullable` here